When is the derived category of a ring generated by injective modules
Are there any equivalent conditions on a ring to the condition that the localizing subcategory of $D(R)$ generated by injective modules is the entire category? Are there any non-examples in Boolean algebras?

Sorry I mean under all colimits (in infinity sense) so I allow all direct sums too

It's still not clear exectly what you mean by "generated by". You edited to replace "injective modules" by "direct sums of injective modules", but I doubt that's what you mean, as the smallest triangulated subcategory containing all direct sums of injective modules is never $D(R)$, as it is contained in the bounded derived category.

Possibly you mean "generated as a triangulated category with coproducts"? A few years ago, I considered this property, not specifically for commutative rings. I didn't find anything like equivalent conditions on a ring, and it's still quite mysterious when "injectives generate" in this sense.

@AndyJiang derived categories don't have colimits beyond direct sums.

I was thinking about the stable infinity enhancement when I spoke about colimits--but closing under direct sums and triangles will do too

Ah ok I guess I should shift in the question

Jeremy Rickard's very interesteing paper gives an answer to the current version of the question.

Yes I agree by support reasons we can generate in all Noetherian commutative case, as pointed out by Jeremy's paper. I'm more interested in the non-Noetherian cases and understanding what this condition says about the ring. Sorry about the miscommunications, I will edit again to try to phrase it better.
